# How to plot trace of the log-posterior (up to proportionality)?

Tags: r, plot, bayesian, jags, rjags

I am working to get some trace plots of posterior from a JAGS model. What is the best way to get the trace plot of the log-posterior (up to proportionality)?

```
mydata = read.table('aaa', header = F)
jmodel = jags.model(file = '111.model', data = list(x = mydata, N = 50, k=2), n.chains = 2)
samps_f = coda.samples(jmodel, variable.names=c('a'), n.iter=1e3)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you are using `rjags`.
You can simply do `plot(samps_f)` as the object has its own plot method.

Looking around, I found [this vignette](https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/272658_ae4d482c86514674be17042c852ebbfc.html) which may also answer other questions you could have.